# ImportError in the matplotlib. Cannot import name '_c_internal_utils'

Tags: python, matplotlib, importerror

Gives an error, attached a screenshot. Tried reinstalling pip and matplotlib , but nothing helps.
By the way, the error looks like this:

```
ImportError: cannot import name '_c_internal_utils' from partially initialized module 'matplotlib' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\dimaw\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py)
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I recommend using the [Anaconda Distribution](https://www.anaconda.com/products/individual), it's likely to make your life much easier.  [Package List](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.8_win-64/)

Comment: both are differnet python one is 3.8 and another is 3.9. change interpreter setting